# Struct Declaration with :

Tags: c, struct

I found this in a sample, but haven't seen ": value;" before in a struct. What is going on here? Are these default values? I didn't think defaults were handled this way for a struct.

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t int2_in_lh           : 1;
  uint8_t drdy_pulsed          : 1;
  uint8_t int2_drdy_temp       : 1;
  uint8_t drdy_mask            : 1;
  uint8_t int2_on_int1         : 1;
  uint8_t not_used0            : 3;
} lsm6dsv16x_ctrl4_t;
```

Comment: They're called bit fields.  They specify tiny integer fields with the given  number of bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It declares a struct data members with explicit size, in bits. Adjacent bit-field members may (or may not) be packed to share and straddle the individual bytes. Use CPP reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field